# SQL Server configuration / specification recommendations and advice!

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am about to deploy a new server at work as follows:
Dell T610
2 x Xeon 2.53 Quad core
24 GB RAM
1 x Perc H700 RAID controller with 1GB Non Volatile memory
8 x 300GB 15k SAS Hard drives

I am looking for recommendations of how to best configure this for use as a SQL server.
I have the following in mind:

Option 1
Allocate a 4GB RAM drive for TempDB
Group all 8 drives into large RAID 10 array for OS, Database and Log files

Option 2
Allocate 4GB RAM drive for TempDB
Use some mixture of RAID arrays (but only have one controller)!

Option 3
Any other suggestions!

For info, the databases in question consist: 1 x 4GB under heavy Read and Write use, 1 x 4GB clone for testing purposes, 2/3 other more minor databases.

Answer (score 7):

What I'd do

- 4 disks for RAID 10 for all log files
- Disk RAID 5 for all data files + OS
- Don't bother with RAM disks

Why?:

- With 24GB RAM all databases will be in memory so RAID 5 doesn't matter because disk reads won't really happen
- Write performance is determined by log file throughput
- Data files are larger then log files so RAID 5 is more efficient

What isn't ideal:

- Not having one volume per database log file
- Separation of local backup drives
- Not having separate RAID 1 for OS + binaries

Other options:

- Define "heavy write": you could go to RAID 1 for LDFs and another for OS for less than a few million rows per day

Comment: OK, Is this beneficial over having all 8 disks in a RAID 10?

Comment: Yes. Different usage pattern of logs vs data means a split is best

Answer (score 1):

Gbn has pretty much covered everything. Just to add, I would put the tempdb on a separate disks from the others.